# Как программно предложить пользователю разрешения из Manifest

Tags: java, android, manifest

**У меня уже есть разрешения в Manifest, но если пользователь удалит и заново установит приложение то эти разрешения не работают, как программно перед началом установки приложения спросить с помощью стандартного диалога все эти разрешения  **

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Вот что я хотел**

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_LOGS,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS


            }, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Добро пожаловать в 2020. Уже несколько лет разрешения запрашиваются не при установке, а при первом запуске или даже при первом вызове функции, требующей эти разрешения. Т.к. задача наистандартнейшая, то решение описано не только в тысячах мануалов, но даже и в официальной документации гугла.

И это еще не все: проверять наличие разрешения нужно **каждый** раз, когда требуется их наличие. И если нет, то снова запрашивать. Пользователь такой - сегодня дал, завтра забрал. Надо всегда исходить их того, что нужных разрешений нет.

И имейте в виду, что начиная с андроида 11 у пользователей будет возможность дать разрешение только на один раз использования.

Официальная документация: [Request app permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Comment: Наверное я не правильно выразился : Как проверять наличие разрешения каждый раз? какие методы использовать? В вотсап или мессенджерах справшивает же, вот как это реализовать?

Comment: Имел в виду:                                                                                                                                                   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We do not have this permission. Let's ask the user
}                                                                                                                                                                                                           но сразу для всех вышеизложенных

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting